# mysql issue node js can insert into

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hi could you please help me with my code? I would like to add some data but i get all the time an error. Here is my code:

```
    var insert_data="INSERT INTO dd_on_call (on_call_start, on_call_end, name) VALUES ? ";
 var test={
  datepicker_from:datepicker_from,
  datepicker_to:datepicker_to,
  hotline_user:hotline_user
  };

    get_sql_data(sql_data, function(err, content) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   res.send(err);  
   // Do something with your error...
   } 
  else {
   sql_data = content;
   console.log(sql_data);
   console.log(test);
   connection.query(insert_data, test, function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render('dd_on_call.ejs',{sql_data:sql_data});  
   });
  };
 });
```

everytime I get this error:

```
[ [ '07 September 18', '14 September 18', 'Ugo' ],
  [ '14 September 18', '21 September 18', 'Erich' ] ]
{ datepicker_from: '2018-09-12 12:00:00',
  datepicker_to: '2018-09-17 12:00:00',
  hotline_user: 'Christian' }
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Project 1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`datepicker_from` = '2018-09-12 12:00:00', `datepicker_to` = '2018-09-17 12:00:0' at line 1
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What are you calling `get_sql_data` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is incomplete, and is missing placeholders for the other two columns which you mentioned.  The raw MySQL query should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dd_on_call (on_call_start, on_call_end, name)
VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

And the JS code should be along these lines:

```
var insert_data = "INSERT INTO dd_on_call (on_call_start, on_call_end, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Your `test` JSON object, which you are using to bind values to the placeholders, looks correct.  The insert should work after making this changes, assuming there are not other errors which I did not catch.

Comment: no this is not working too.

<code>
{ datepicker_from: '2018-09-12 12:00:00',
  datepicker_to: '2018-09-21 12:00:00',
  hotline_user: 'Ugo' }
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Project 1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1